# Adonisjs models name when schema contains "_" character

Tags: node.js, model, schema, adonis.js

I created a schema called "brand_types". Now I want to create a model for it, but if I call it "BrandType" lucid doesn't recognize the schema since it contains the "_" character. How can I tell the model which is the right schema?

EDIT:
I tried this

```
 static get table () {
        return 'smart_contract_types'
    }
```

But it still doesn't work with seeders.

Comment: Do you use v4 or v5? can you share your seeds code?

Comment: Adonis v4.1 I have declared a factory for that model and then I call the factory from the seed file. It works for models like users and customers